# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call: Use setNull for user-defined types and REF types

Tags: java, plsql

I'm trying to call a Stored Procedure using Java.

I've looked through similar errors and already tried copying the solutions and Still having errors.

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call: Use setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType, String typeName) for user-defined types and REF types

```
import java.sql*;

public class FusionDBConnection {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("RUN PROCESS START");

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.XX.XXX.XXX:1521:AAA1", "TEST", "TESTPASS");

        CallableStatement cst = dbConn.prepareCall("{call EDGF.FMW_SELECT_PACS_SEQ(?,?,?,?)}");

        cst.setString(1,"A");
        cst.setString(2, "B");
        cst.setString(3,"C");
        cst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.REF);
        cst.registerOutParameter(4,Types.REF);

        ResultSet outData = (ResultSet)cst.getObject(4); 

        while (outData.next()) {
            System.out.println(outData.getString(4));
        }
        dbConn.close();
        System.out.println("RUN PROCESS END");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Stored Procedure

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE FMW_SELECT_PACS_SEQ 
(
  IN_RECORDTYPE IN VARCHAR2  
, IN_CODE IN VARCHAR2 
, IN_GENERATIONNUMBER IN VARCHAR2 
, PACSSEQRESULTS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
SELECTPACSSEQ VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
--SELECT PACS_SEQ
SELECTPACSSEQ := 

'SELECT RECORD_TYPE, CODE, GENERATION_NUMBER, STATUS, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_DATE FROM EDGF.EDGF_PACS_SEQUENCES 
WHERE RECORD_TYPE ='''||IN_RECORDTYPE||''' AND CODE = '''||IN_CODE||'''AND GENERATION_NUMBER ='''||IN_GENERATIONNUMBER||'''';
OPEN PACSSEQRESULTS FOR SELECTPACSSEQ;

END FMW_SELECT_PACS_SEQ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read, you should not be calling a setter on the OUT parameter, since it is not designed to receive any input value from the outside.  So, remove this line:

```
cst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.REF);
```

Also, you should register the fourth OUT parameter as an Oracle cursor, so use this:

```
cst.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

So, your updated configuration code might look like this:

```
cst.setString(1,"A");
cst.setString(2, "B");
cst.setString(3,"C");
cst.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

If you don't already have the required dependencies for `OracleTypes`, then [visit here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html) and download the `ojdbc` Oracle JAR.  You may need a slightly different link depending on your Oracle version (the above link is for `12c`).

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for the answer, but OracleTypes is not defined. What library should I import?

Comment: @user10888192 You are missing an Oracle JDBC JAR, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much this sovled the problem for me. I used this instruction for adding Oracle JDBC http://www.oracledistilled.com/java/adding-the-oracle-jdbc-drivers-to-a-jdeveloper-11gr1-project/